# set values for URLTypes in info.plist through apple script

Tags: scripting, applescript

I want to set the values in info.plist file for URLTypes like below

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLName</key>
<string>com.test.testLaunch</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>LaunchApp1</string>
<string>LaunchApp2</string>
</array>
</dict>
</array>
```

I am trying the below approach but it does not work.

```
tell property list file plistFile
tell contents
set value of property list item "CFBundleURLTypes" of property list item "CFBundleURLName" to "New Key Value"
end tell
end tell
```

What should I do to set all the values for the CFBundleURLTypes key and set the nested values for dictionary and array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applescript equivalents are array = list and dictionary = record, so just make a list of records. One record has a value of a string and the other one has a value of an array of strings. Note: I haven't tested this but it's worth a try.

```
set myArray to {{CFBundleURLName:"com.test.testLaunch"}, {CFBundleURLSchemes:{"LaunchApp1", "LaunchApp2"}}}
tell application "System Events"
    set plistFile to property list file "some:path"
    tell plistFile
        tell contents
            set value of property list item "CFBundleURLTypes" to myArray
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```